# Autosys Job scheduling- With Month and Day condition

Tags: conditional-statements, scheduling, autosys

I need to run a Box in Autosys using scheduler with condition 1st day of every month and every Saturday.

I tried to add run_calendar and days_of_week: sa but this does not work.

Please let me know how to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

extended calendar can have such conditions.

Create an extended calendar as

```
extended_calendar: Cal_name
description: runs on 1st day of the month and sat
workday: mo,tu,we,th,fr
non_workday:  
holiday:  
holcal: 
cyccal: 
adjust: 0
condition: MNTHD#1|sat
```

Use this calendar for your job.

condition: MNTHD#1|sat

**MNTHD#1** 1st day of every month

**|**       AND

**sat**     every saturday.

refer this link for more such conditions
[Autosys calendar conditions](https://docops.ca.com/ca-workload-automation-ae/11-4-2/en/scheduling/ae-scheduling/manage-your-calendars/date-condition-keywords)

Hope this helps.